# How to set default value in catalog category add products to categories in position column

Tags: magento2, category, grid

I have attached screenshot, I want to add default values in position, for example when I add product in category position should show 100.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have set my default position for products to 100 by using this patch. This sets it to 100 when a product is added to a new category.

```
    @package magento/module-catalog

diff --git a/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php b/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php
--- a/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php
+++ b/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php    (date 1666682384544)
@@ -513,7 +513,7 @@
             $categoryLink = $categoryLinks[$categoryId] ??
                 $this->categoryLinkFactory->create()
                     ->setCategoryId($categoryId)
-                    ->setPosition(0);
+                    ->setPosition(100);
             $newCategoryLinks[] = $categoryLink;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had done this I was overriden some magento core functionalities.